# Auto-increment release version Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have an application that builds in Jenkins and that I want to deploy to Octopus. When I am doing this I have to create a release version that is send to Octopus. For this release version I have to give a number (ex: `"C:\Octopus\Octo.exe" create-release --project APP --version 4.8 --packageversion=4.8`)

How can I make so that version number will be auto-incremented ? (ex: I have build the application and created in Octopus the release version number 4.8, the next time I build the application I want to create the release version number 4.9)

Thank you

Comment: Jenkins is a CI tool. Managing version numbers is a Build Management tool's task. I do not see an other solution but using a hand-made process in your case.

Comment: @GeroldBroser can you please give me an example on how can I achieve this ? Thx

Comment: See [GROM – Generalized Release Order Management](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/131584/58906). As soon as it is revised there I'm going to post it as an answer, including Jenkins, here.

Comment: Jenkins has auto incrementing BUILD_NUMBER.  Could you pass some thing like "--version 4.${BUILD_NUMBER}?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a job property to store the version, and then update it on each run with the following script (executed by "Execute system groovy script" build step):

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.*

def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def jobName = "yourJobName"
String versionType = "minor"
def job = jenkins.getItem(jobName)

//get the current version parameter and update its default value
paramsDef = job.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)
if (paramsDef) {
   paramsDef.parameterDefinitions.each{
       if("version".equals(it.name)){
           println "Current version is ${it.defaultValue}"
           it.defaultValue = getUpdatedVersion(versionType, it.defaultValue)
           println "Next version is ${it.defaultValue}"
       }
   }
}

//determine the next version by the required type 
//and incrementing the current version

def getUpdatedVersion(String versionType, String currentVersion){

    def split = currentVersion.split('\\.')
    switch (versionType){
        case "minor.minor":
            split[2]=++Integer.parseInt(split[2])
            break
        case "minor":
            split[1]=++Integer.parseInt(split[1])
            break;
        case "major":
           split[0]=++Integer.parseInt(split[0])
           break;
    }
    return split.join('.')
}
```

Comment: At least on my version of jenkins this code doesn't update the job's config.xml file so on a restart this incremented number can be lost.  After updating the value you'll want to have a line in the script `job.save()` to save the change to the filesystem.

Comment: This method gives me `0.2.13` for `getUpdatedVersion('minor', '0.1.13')`. I would expect it to be `0.2.0`. Also, `++` on something that's not a variable seems like a very bad practice.

Answer (score 16):

If you are doing deployments from a git repo, you are probably already creating tags for each release (or you should at least, so that you can more easily track what was deployed). If that's the case, you can just derive the next release version from those tags, without having to store the version anywhere else (just make sure Jenkins is fetching tags in advanced clone behaviours).

Then, you can calculate the next version with something like this:

```groovy
def nextVersionFromGit(scope) {
    def latestVersion = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --match *.*.* 2> /dev/null || echo 0.0.0').trim()
    def (major, minor, patch) = latestVersion.tokenize('.').collect { it.toInteger() }
    def nextVersion
    switch (scope) {
        case 'major':
            nextVersion = "${major + 1}.0.0"
            break
        case 'minor':
            nextVersion = "${major}.${minor + 1}.0"
            break
        case 'patch':
            nextVersion = "${major}.${minor}.${patch + 1}"
            break
    }
    nextVersion
}
```

This method uses [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) format, but it can be easily adapted if you want versions with only 2 numbers.

Comment: in groovy, is there a way to default patch to 0 if say there is only a major and minor.

Answer (score 9):

Jenkins provides some [environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) available to each build command; one of those is the build number, an increasing number.

If you can accommodate with holes in your version numbers, change your version to include the build number, like 4.8-142 where 142 is the build number from jenkins. This gives you increasing version numbers in the semver sense and still let you control the real version in a more functional way.

If you are not happy with the build number in your version, then you should have a post build script that updates the version number and stores that in a file somewhere. You could then inject that file content with either the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) or using a [parametrized build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

Comment: After reading all the answers above this, I was going to suggest using the build number.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Use **version Number plugin** from Jenkins Plugins, It should give you an environment variable to use as virsion number see more in this [URL](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin)

Answer (score 1):

I used this piece bellow:

```
export RELEASE_VERSION=$(jx-release-version) 

git tag -fa v${RELEASE_VERSION} -m 'Release version ${RELEASE_VERSION}' 

git push origin v${RELEASE_VERSION}
```

https://www.jenkins.io/projects/gsoc/2021/project-ideas/semantic-release-version/